# How to optimise a stored procedure that is too slow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, query-performance

My stored procedure is taking around 1 minute 45 seconds, how can I optimize it? I tried couple of things like creating temp table before doing the insert.

I have Estimated Execution Plan but I don't know how to upload it.

This is part of my stored procedure which is taking longer time and Query Cost is 53%.

```
SELECT Distinct
    BackupCTE.[InstanceName]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.EnvironmentType = 0 THEN '-1' Else CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.EnvironmentType) END  AS EnvironmentType
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceStatus = 0 THEN '-1' Else CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.InstanceStatus) END AS [InstanceStatus] 
   ,BackupCTE.[BackupShare]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.DatabaseOwner = 0 THEN '-1'
          WHEN ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsMirroringEnabled,0) = 0 AND BackupCTE.DatabaseOwner NOT IN ('SA') AND BackupCTE.DatabaseStatus = 'Normal' AND BackupCTE.DatabaseReadOnly = 0
              AND ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsDatabaseSnapshot,0) = 0 THEN '0'
         ELSE '1' END AS DatabaseOwner
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.DBRecoveryModel = 0 THEN '-1' 
          WHEN BackupCTE.DatabaseStatus = 'Normal' AND BackupCTE.DatabaseName NOT IN ('master', 'msdb', 'IHC_DBA','distribution','ReportServerTempDB','NavicareReporting','ReportServer') AND
               BackupCTE.RecoveryModel NOT IN ('Full','BulkLogged') THEN '0'
          ELSE '1'
    END AS [DBRecoveryModel]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.AutoShrink = 0 THEN '-1'              
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, BackupCTE.[AutoShrink]) END AS [AutoShrink]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.AutoClose = 0 THEN '-1' Else CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.[AutoClose]) END AS [AutoClose]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.BackupCompression = 0 THEN '-1' 
          WHEN BackupCTE.[BackupCompression] = 0 THEN '0'
          Else '1' END AS [BackupCompression]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.XPCmdShell = 0 THEN '-1' 
         WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.[XPCmdShell]) = 0 THEN '1'
         Else '0' END AS [XPCmdShell]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.EncryptionEnabled = 0 THEN '-1' Else CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.[EncryptionEnabled]) END AS [EncryptionEnabled]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.IsIdera = 0 THEN '-1' Else CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.[IsIdera]) END AS [IsIdera]
   ,[HoursRetentionShare]
   ,[HoursSinceLastFullBackup]
   ,[HoursSinceLastDiffBackup]
   ,[HoursSinceLastLogBackup]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.ExceededBkpTimeFrame = 0 THEN '-1' Else BackupCTE.ExceededBkpTimeFrame 
    END AS ExceededBkpTimeFrame
   ,BackupType
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[Primary] = 0 THEN '-1' Else BackupCTE.[Primary] END AS [Primary]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[Secondary] = 0 THEN '-1' Else BackupCTE.[Secondary] END AS [Secondary]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[LockPages] = 0 THEN '-1' 
        Else CONVERT(varchar,BackupCTE.[LockPages]) END  AS [LockPages]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[SADisabled] = 0 THEN '-1'  
         WHEN CONVERT(varchar,BackupCTE.[SADisabled]) = 0 AND BackupCTE.VersionName like 'Microsoft SQL Server  2000 %' THEN '1' 
         ELSE CONVERT(varchar,BackupCTE.[SADisabled])
         END AS [SADisabled]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.ServiceAccount = 0 THEN '-1'
         WHEN StdServiceAccount.IsValid = 1
                    OR BackupCTE.ServiceAccount IN ('CO\lpsqldbadmin','lpsqldbadmin@CO.IHC.COM')                
            THEN  '1'
            ELSE '0' END AS ServiceAccount
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[ServicePackFlag] = 0 THEN '-1' Else BackupCTE.[ServicePack] END AS [ServicePack]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[MaxMemory] = 0 THEN '-1' Else BackupCTE.[MaxMemory] END AS [MaxMemory]
   ,[JobName]
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[JobOwner] = 0 THEN '-1'
         WHEN BackupCTE.JobOwner NOT IN ('SA') AND JobEnabled = 1 AND DELETED IS NULL THEN '0' 
         ELSE '1' END AS JobOwner 
   ,[JobEnabled]
   ,CASE WHEN BackupCTE.EnvironmentType = 'PROD' AND BackupCTE.[Primary] NOT IN ('Tamie Jensen', 'Chase Mahony','Megna Musapeta','Aaron Uppencamp') THEN '0' 
         WHEN BackupCTE.EnvironmentType = 'STBY' AND BackupCTE.[Primary] NOT IN ('Tamie Jensen', 'Chase Mahony','Megna Musapeta','Aaron Uppencamp') THEN '0'
         ELSE '1' END AS IsNonPrimary
   ,CASE WHEN BackupCTE.EnvironmentType = 'PROD' AND BackupCTE.[Secondary] IN ('NONE') THEN '0' 
         WHEN BackupCTE.EnvironmentType = 'STBY' AND BackupCTE.[Secondary] IN ('NONE') THEN '0'
         ELSE '1' END AS IsNonSecondary
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.[MaxMemory] = 0 THEN '-1' 
         WHEN BackupCTE.[MaxMemory]%8 = 0 THEN '1' 
         ELSE '0' END AS FlagMemory
   ,CASE WHEN BackupCTE.JobName NOT LIKE '%Insure%'
   THEN
       CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.MaintenanceJob = 0 THEN '-1'
              WHEN JobSchMultiplier < 0 THEN '1' --One Time Job. No Need To Flag
              WHEN DATEDIFF(HH, BackupCTE.JobRunDate, GETDATE()) > 24*JobSchMultiplier THEN '0'
              ELSE '1'            
        END
    ELSE '1' END  AS MaintenanceJob
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.ServicePackFlag = 0 THEN '-1'
          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(PatchingStds.ServicePack,3, LEN(PatchingStds.ServicePack)-2))) > ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(InstanceSQLDTl.ServicePack,3, 
              LEN(InstanceSQLDTl.ServicePack)-2))),0) THEN '0'
         WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(VersionName,CHARINDEX('-',VersionName )+1,abs(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',VersionName ) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('(',VersionName )-CHARINDEX('-',VersionName) ELSE len(VersionName)-CHARINDEX('-',VersionName)  end)))) <> LTRIM(RTRIM(PatchingStds.SQLBuild)) THEN '2'
         ELSE '1' END AS ServicePackFlag
   ,VersionName 
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.SAViolations = 0 THEN '-1'
         WHEN LoginName Not IN ('CO\DBA Group','CO\DBAdmin') AND SYSAdmin = 1 OR SecurityAdmin = 1 OR ServerAdmin = 1 OR SetupAdmin = 1 OR ProcessAdmin = 1 OR DiskAdmin = 1
                                                             OR DBCreator = 1 OR BulkAdmin = 1 THEN '0'
         ELSE '1' END AS SAViolations 
   ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.IsBackupShare = 0 THEN '-1'
         WHEN NOT (BackupCTE.[BackupShare] LIKE '\\CO.IHC.COM%' OR BackupCTE.[BackupShare] LIKE '\\CO-LP-SQL1%' OR BackupCTE.[BackupShare] LIKE '\\CO-LP-SQL2%' 
               OR BackupCTE.[BackupShare] LIKE '\\CO-TX-VAULT2%' OR BackupCTE.[BackupShare] LIKE '\\co-tx-vpdsfile2\txPDSsqlBackups%' AND BackupCTE.[BackupShare] NOT LIKE '%Test') OR BackupCTE.[BackupShare] = 'NONE LISTED' THEN '0'
         ELSE '1' END AS IsBackupShare
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.Tempdb_DataFileCount = 0 THEN '-1'
          WHEN TEMPDBFileCount.Tempdb_DataFileCount >= 8 OR TEMPDBFileCount.Tempdb_DataFileCount > TEMPDBFileCount.OptimalTempdbFilecount THEN '1'
          WHEN TEMPDBFileCount.OptimalTempdbFilecount > TEMPDBFileCount.Tempdb_DataFileCount THEN '0'
          ELSE '1'END AS Tempdb_DataFileCount
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.DataAutoGrow = 0 THEN '-1' ELSE BackupCTE.DataAutoGrow END AS DataAutoGrow
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.LogAutoGrow = 0 THEN '-1' ELSE BackupCTE.LogAutoGrow END AS LogAutoGrow
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.MaintVersion = 0 THEN '-1' ELSE BackupCTE.MaintVersion END AS MaintVersion
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.MaintVersion = 0 THEN '-1' 
         WHEN BackupCTE.MaintVersion = 2.02 OR BackupCTE.MaintVersion = 2.03 THEN '1'
         ELSE '0' END AS FlagMaintVersion
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.DBCompatibilityLevel = 0 THEN '-1' 
          WHEN BackupCTE.DBCompatibilityLevel < 90 THEN '0'
          ELSE '1' END AS DBCompatibilityLevel
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.FlagVersionName = 0 THEN '-1' 
          WHEN NOT (BackupCTE.VersionName LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server 2005%' OR BackupCTE.VersionName LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server  2000%') THEN '1'
          ELSE '0' END AS FlagVersionName
    ,CASE WHEN DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL AND ComplianceReportExceptions.VLFCount = 0 THEN '-1' 
          ELSE BackupCTE.VLFCount END AS VLFCount
Into #FinalData
FROM [DBAPP].InstanceSQLDtl 
LEFT JOIN #BackupCTE BackupCTE ON  InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = BackupCTE.InstanceID
LEFT JOIN  [DBAPP].[SQLPatchingStandards] PatchingStds ON LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(VersionName, CHARINDEX('-', VersionName)-1))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT
           (PatchingStds.SQLVersion,CHARINDEX('-',PatchingStds.SQLVersion)-1))) 
LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[ComplianceReportExceptions] ON ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName =  BackupCTE.InstanceName
LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[TEMPDBFileCount] ON InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = [TEMPDBFileCount].InstanceID AND Type_DESC = 'ROWS'
LEFT JOIN DBO.fnGetServiceNames() StdServiceAccount ON BackupCTE.InstanceID = StdServiceAccount.InstanceID
Where BackupCTE.[InstanceName] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [InstanceName]
```

Comment: So you drop a stored proc with nearly 500 lines and no details on a forum and expect somebody to be able to help????

Comment: You'e parsing strings and using UDFs in the joins... I'd say you're lucky it finishes at all...

Comment: Now it is just over 100 lines. But still....without table definitions and execution plans there is little anybody can do here. That function fnGetServiceNames is probably where I would start though.

Answer (score 2):

That much string manipulation and CASE statements are just always going to be slow. Maybe you can run it as a nightly batch process into a datamart? Otherwise, here are a few tips:

1. Since many of your CASE statements are testing for ...InstanceName IS NULL, you can split the query in half and use UNION ALL to join together the records where it is and is not null (see example). This will remove a bunch of CASE checks.
2. Don't use WHERE IN('SA') if there's only one item, use not-equal (<>) instead.
3. If at all possible, avoid doing string manipulation in a JOIN condition (`...PatchingStds ON LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(VersionName...`). Try to store those fields somewhere, either in a dedicated column or as persisted, computed columns. That way you can put in index on that field to make the join much faster.
4. Have indexes on the join fields where possible, subject to many factors, but mostly just don't have too many indexes on a single table because that will slow down INSERT statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BackupCTE.[InstanceName]
   , EnvironmentType = CASE WHEN ComplianceReportExceptions.EnvironmentType = 0 THEN '-1' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, BackupCTE.EnvironmentType) END
   , [InstanceStatus] = CASE WHEN ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceStatus = 0 THEN '-1' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.InstanceStatus) END 
   , BackupCTE.[BackupShare]
   , DatabaseOwner = 
        CASE WHEN ComplianceReportExceptions.DatabaseOwner = 0 THEN '-1'
             WHEN ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsMirroringEnabled,0) = 0 
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseOwner <> 'SA'
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseStatus = 'Normal' 
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseReadOnly = 0
                AND ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsDatabaseSnapshot,0) = 0 
            THEN '0'
            ELSE '1' 
         END
    -- Etc...
INTO #FinalData
FROM [DBAPP].InstanceSQLDtl 
    LEFT JOIN #BackupCTE BackupCTE ON  InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = BackupCTE.InstanceID
    LEFT JOIN  [DBAPP].[SQLPatchingStandards] PatchingStds ON LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(VersionName, CHARINDEX('-', VersionName)-1))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT
               (PatchingStds.SQLVersion,CHARINDEX('-',PatchingStds.SQLVersion)-1))) 
    LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[ComplianceReportExceptions] ON ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName =  BackupCTE.InstanceName
    LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[TEMPDBFileCount] ON InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = [TEMPDBFileCount].InstanceID AND Type_DESC = 'ROWS'
    LEFT JOIN DBO.fnGetServiceNames() StdServiceAccount ON BackupCTE.InstanceID = StdServiceAccount.InstanceID
WHERE BackupCTE.[InstanceName] IS NOT NULL
    AND DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NOT NULL
--****************
UNION ALL 
--****************
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BackupCTE.[InstanceName]
   , EnvironmentType = CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.EnvironmentType)
   , [InstanceStatus] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,BackupCTE.InstanceStatus)
   , BackupCTE.[BackupShare]
   , DatabaseOwner = 
       CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsMirroringEnabled,0) = 0 
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseOwner <> 'SA'
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseStatus = 'Normal' 
                AND BackupCTE.DatabaseReadOnly = 0
                AND ISNULL(BackupCTE.IsDatabaseSnapshot,0) = 0 
            THEN '0'
            ELSE '1' 
        END
-- Etc...
INTO #FinalData
FROM [DBAPP].InstanceSQLDtl 
    LEFT JOIN #BackupCTE BackupCTE ON  InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = BackupCTE.InstanceID
    LEFT JOIN  [DBAPP].[SQLPatchingStandards] PatchingStds ON LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(VersionName, CHARINDEX('-', VersionName)-1))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT
               (PatchingStds.SQLVersion,CHARINDEX('-',PatchingStds.SQLVersion)-1))) 
    LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[ComplianceReportExceptions] ON ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName =  BackupCTE.InstanceName
    LEFT JOIN [DBAPP].[TEMPDBFileCount] ON InstanceSQLDtl.InstanceID = [TEMPDBFileCount].InstanceID AND Type_DESC = 'ROWS'
    LEFT JOIN DBO.fnGetServiceNames() StdServiceAccount ON BackupCTE.InstanceID = StdServiceAccount.InstanceID
WHERE BackupCTE.[InstanceName] IS NOT NULL
    AND DBAPP.ComplianceReportExceptions.InstanceName IS NULL
--****************
ORDER BY [InstanceName]
```

Comment: Divide and Conquer is a good way to start resolving this.

Answer (score -1):

Below are the possibilities which causes to degrade the performance of an query,

> 1. Do not convert colum value at on clause instead of this create a separate colum and pre-populated the conversion, if you use conversion
>    it prohibit using indexes to search records in table.
> 2. Use with(nolock)
> 3. Distinct & order by are costly operations to the query , if you don’t required remove it from query.